# Use Slick.js custom pseudo-classes in regular CSS

Tags: javascript, css, mootools, slick.js

I want to create some [custom pseudo classes using Slick](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Slick/Slick#Slick:Slick-definePseudo) like this

```js
Slick.definePseudo('in-fold', function(){
    var isInFold = false;
    // code to determine if the element is visible in the viewport
    return isInFold;
});
```

and then use those pseudo-classes in  regular CSS like so

```css
nav:in-fold {
    display: static;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.2em
}
```

If this is possible at all, I couldn't get it to work. Am I missing anything?

If this is not possible using Slick.js, is there another way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick pseudos can only be used when querying elements with Slick (and Mootools), you cannot use them in CSS. You could try to add some JS code to apply and remove regular CSS classes when the `in-fold` pseudo can change (scroll and resize), but be aware of performances:

```
var updateInFoldStyle = function() {
    $$('nav.in-fold-class').removeClass('in-fold-class');
    $$('nav:in-fold').addClass('in-fold-class');
};

window.addEvent('scroll', updateInFoldStyle);
window.addEvent('resize', updateInFoldStyle);
```

Some ideas if performance is poor:

- avoid removing and re-adding class when not needed;
- use the `:pause` [pseudo event](http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.6.0/Class/Events.Pseudos#Pseudos:pause) to avoid firing `scroll` and `resize` events too frequently.